# SQL Server How to update value in xml by XQuery when some part is dynamic

Tags: t-sql, xquery

I have to replace all text **~Total Revenue~** with **~Gross Revenue~** which is stored GroupKey tag.

see the below code which is working perfectly.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
 INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
 (N'<PWR_ViewAll>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Net Income~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
 </PWR_ViewAll>');
 -- DDL and sample data population, end
    
 DECLARE @from VARCHAR(30) = '~Total Revenue~'
    , @to VARCHAR(30) = '~Gross Revenue~';
    
 -- before
 SELECT * FROM @tbl
 WHERE xmldata.exist('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]') = 1;
    
 DECLARE @UPDATE_STATUS BIT = 1;
    
 WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0
 BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET xmldata.modify('replace value of (/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]/text())[1]
       with (sql:column("t1.c"))')
    FROM @tbl AS t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(xmldata.value('(/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),@from,@to)) AS t1(c)
    WHERE xmldata.exist('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]') = 1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
    PRINT @UPDATE_STATUS;
 END;
    
 -- after
 SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**The issue is** This element is not fixed **/PWR_ViewAll/** in XML because it could be

**/AWS_ViewAll/ OR /TTWO_ViewAll/** etc

so how to refactor above code as a result i can make this part **/PWR_ViewAll/** dynamic. please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out and now attaching code which is working.

```
DECLARE @Ticker_ViewAll VARCHAR(MAX)='/PWR_ViewAll'
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
 INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
 (N'<PWR_ViewAll>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
     <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
         <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
         <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
         <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
         <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Net Income~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
     </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
 </PWR_ViewAll>');
 -- DDL and sample data population, end
    
 DECLARE @from VARCHAR(30) = '~Total Revenue~'
    , @to VARCHAR(30) = '~Gross Revenue~';
    
 -- before
 SELECT * FROM @tbl
 WHERE xmldata.exist('/*/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]') = 1;
    
 DECLARE @UPDATE_STATUS BIT = 1;
    
 WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0
 BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET xmldata.modify('replace value of (/*/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]/text())[1]
       with (sql:column("t1.c"))')
    FROM @tbl AS t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(xmldata.value('(/*/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),@from,@to)) AS t1(c)
    WHERE xmldata.exist('/*/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@from"))]') = 1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
    PRINT @UPDATE_STATUS;
 END;
    
 -- after
 SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```